# Should questions have a backstory in them, or should it be edited out?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

So yesterday I stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312948/powershell-code-for-my-sons-birthday).

First of all, I am amazed at how well received the question was. Not only does it have 5 answers, but I don't think I have ever personally witnessed 20 up-votes on a question in less than 24 hours. Anyway...

When you actually consider the question, it is clear that the information is mostly just a story about why the OP it writing some code/script. If you were to remove everything that wasn't actually related to the code/problem, the new question would be:

---

SUBJECT: Powershell Code

This is what I have...

```
$day=11/21/2017
$today=Get-Date
if (Today=$day)
{echo"Happy 18th Birthday [Jular]"}
else
{echo"Eat Cake Anyways"}
```

---

There is no described problem, no specific error, no information about what the OP is trying to achieve (although yes, you could speculate from the code).

Now I am pretty sure that cut-down question would get absolutely destroyed. Mass downvotes, closed within minutes, and likely deleted. Yet because of the 'back story' people have decided they *like* the question and that normal SO rules don't apply.

I believe we do generally say that questions shouldn't contain irrelevant information (certainly for example: greetings and thanks).

So would the correct action in this case be to remove the back-story as I have highlighted? Should only part of it be removed? Should it be left alone? In this example, the answers to my questions would have a big effect on the outcome of the original post.

Essentially, whether it was intentional or not, the OP has managed to cheat the system and get good answers to an otherwise very poor question, and my overall concern is how we should handle these kind of scenarios going forward.

Comment: The walls of code some answers expect to fit on a cake... o.O

Comment: Regarding the upvotes, it seems it entered HNQ at some time. Googling the exact title returned some sites other than SO, which only means that it appeared on the HNQ sidebar. Anyway, "answering" the meta question... backstory could be needed, as long as it add context to the problem. In this case... nah.

Comment: The cake is a lie.

Comment: With the question in mind, how about answers which acknowledge the backstory of the question, should those instances be edited out? For example, *definitely a cool idea for your son!* or *It could be much worse ;-)*.

Comment: I voted to close as "primarily opinion-based", as it seemed primed to solicit a bunch of "no, I think *this* looks nicer" answers -- as it did. "What code should go on a birthday cake" is a nice question as far as warm fuzzies go, but it has no place on SO. That said, there's a clear "does this code work and if not, how do I correct it" question underlying it that is on topic for SO, although still not good as a question. In the end, this question is simply not of sufficient quality to bother with either way (but at least much more emotionally pleasing than most other bad questions).

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Yeah, I can see a way to make the question on topic (as I actually commented myself), but I don't think what you say about "does his code work" is on topic... OP should be telling us what specifically about it doesn't work, right? Show error message etc. Then why ask, is this useful to future visitors.. I think it fits pretty much every close reason...

Comment: @Script47: A good point, but personally if the answer solves the *actual* problem then it doesn't bother me. But you are right that if you edit out the back story in the question, should you also remove any references to it in answers... perhaps the answer is you shouldn't remove stuff from questions that have already been answered?

Comment: You're technically correct (the best kind of correct!) but since showing what's wrong with the code amounts to pasting it in a PowerShell window and watching the errors (which, admittedly, the OP could of course have done) I don't see that as the major red flag. In general, dumping code and not asking what the issue is is of course a reason to close, but for very small snippets like this I tend not to stand on ceremony.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Yeah, we all have different acceptance levels, and even posting code at all for a first time user is a welcome rarity these days. It can be difficult to know the correct course of action, hence my question here

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91219/does-a-question-about-birthday-cakes-for-programmers-have-a-home

Comment: This was kind of a mean thing to do to that post, attempting to invoke the ire of meta because you personally disliked the backstory. It's not like **[you haven't asked for code in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13864272/1026459)**. All this post had really done was instead of dryly explaining that the equality wasn't working with nothing else, gave a little bit of backstory. Now, I agree that the question is not the highest quality, but that doesn't warrant what you have done here.

Comment: I saw people having fun. I downvoted them all.

Comment: @TravisJ: I didn't say anything about disliking the backstory, in fact I think it's quite nice. This discussion is about if it is appropriate or not, and the correct action to take. Also, again, I didn't say anything about a problem with "asking for code", I said there is no specific issue, or requirement, or problem. With regards to the code, there is no actual information. And are you suggesting that I should lower my quality of question in Meta by not being allowed to post example questions? I don't care how many up or down votes that question gets, I just wanted to know what we should do

Comment: @musefan - It seems there are a lot of posts just innocently asking "what we should do" about individual posts they take issue with lately. Also, your introduction paragraph in this post pretty much directly contradicts your comment.

Comment: @Musefan - Please don't mince words here. The tone of your post, the implication that the question normally would be destroyed, the reference to mass downvotes, the way you phrased this entire post, is essentially a rant against this specific question, and not backstory in general.

Comment: It belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @TravisJ: Well regardless of how you 'interpreted' my post, I know exactly the reason I posted it. If you don't want to accept that then that's up to you. When something I think should be downvoted gets 20 upvotes then it makes me question my reasoning. Yes this post my seem to unfairly focus on a single example, but it was that single example that is the sole reason for my to want to find out what we should be doing about questions like that. And my first paragraph, yes the amazement is what leads me to question my downvote after seeing 20 other users make the opposite decision to me

Comment: @Victoria: I though I read someone else already mention code review, and that code review has a requirement to only include valid working code? (not code that doesn't work). So not sure it would work over there either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd argue to stop worrying. This single instance is not evidence of a problem that needs addressing. So it has a cute backstory which people appreciate. Most of whom probably don't even know or care about what the "rules" are that us grumpy bastards cling to.

Just close it (which it is by now) and that's it. If we really find ourselves with an influx of questions cheating the system by coming up with contrived cute backstories, we have something to discuss. And if we get questions which are actually great and have a little non-distracting backstory, the occasional blind eye will do.

We hate fun, but only to prevent everything from getting away with "just being for fun". Don't sweat the occasional display of non-grumpiness.

Comment: I would also worry that removing backstory too aggressively can end up with important context being removed.  A lot of questions leave out the "why" they are trying to do something in a certain way and end looking like an XY problem (which they may or may not be).  Often, the backstory, though sometimes too verbose, includes important tidbits, like _why_.

Comment: Yeah I think I am happy to just vote close and move on, and that was initially what I had done. It was only that in this instance I had been drawn back to the question (probably a comment notification) the next day, and was surprised to see that 20 people didn't agree with me. Seeing that many upvotes for what I thought was a bad question just makes me question my decision.

Answer (score 12):

The "backstory" is fine. It *is* relevant to the code/question, and removing it would damage the question (further).

Reading your post before I saw the question, I was expecting to see a huge wall of irrelevant text - but instead I saw basically the minimum explanation required to justify the (off-topic) requirements: syntactically correct, "fun" code for a cake.

It's off-topic of course, but not because of the backstory. And I say that as someone who constantly edits out fluff from questions.

Comment: hmmm... I see your point that it is technically requirements about the task the OP is trying to achieve, but then it;s nothing to do with the code. It doesn't even say something like: "So I would like the code to be correct on the cake, could you help me check this code is valid?" There really isn't even a question at all... for all we know its just an announcement that some person is going to make a cake with that specific piece of code on, and they just wanted to let the internet know about it

Comment: The backstory is still way too long though. 7 sentences for what basically boils down to "I wrote the below Powershell code for a code-themed cake", which is of course not a question.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the introduction and the story behind the question, the post should be closed (and it is for now) because it's not really clear, and it also doesn't demonstrate understanding of the problem.

I downvoted the question not because it has this cute introduction, but because it doesn't meet the standards of Stack Overflow in the sense of its clearness and completeness.

Please note that there might be questions that includes a funny background story, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently):

> Yesterday I was pairing the socks from the clean laundry and figured out the way I was doing it is not very efficient.

But it's clear that this question is very clear, complete and demonstrate a good understanding of what OP is trying to achieve.

In conclusion, the question should be closed not because the story, but mainly **because it's unclear**.

---

I just want to mention that I don't encourage long and redundant stories, as they may make it more difficult for the search functionality to yield good and accurate results. But in some cases, it doesn't harm to add a small intro if it doesn't go too much far.

Comment: Yeah I agree, and in past tend to overlook an irrelevant line or two as long as there is enough of the good stuff in the question. Its good that my example question has been closed, but I am still unsure... should we remove the junk, or just leave it and like you say, review the question as if it wasnt there?

Comment: @musefan I think that it depends on the question and on how it was asked. On the specific question you're talking about, the backstory is really long, and the question doesn't meet the SO standards. In this case, I think I would've edited the question and removed the story.